# get value of angular js expression in window.alert in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html

Hi I am trying to alert the value of an expression in angularJs

I am quite new to angular and am just trying to work out how grab the value of the expression in an alert or in the console.

I am using AngularJs with json, below is my code

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="menu in menus" id="{{menu.id}}" class="{{menu.cssClass}}">
        <a ng-href="{{menu.content}}" ng-click="doGreeting(greeting)">{{menu.description}}</a>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="submenu in menu.menu" id="{{submenu.id}}" class="{{submenu.cssClass}}">
            <a ng-href="{{submenu.content}}" ng-click="ShowAlert()">{{submenu.description}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", "$window",
  function($scope, $http, $window) {
    $http.get('menu.json')
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.menus = response.data.menus; // response data
        $scope.greeting = 'Hello, World!';
        $scope.ShowAlert = function () {
            $window.alert("{{menu.content}}");
        }
      });
  }
]);
```

**JSON**

```
{
   "menus":[
      {
         "id":"contact",
         "leaf":true,
         "description":"Contact Us",
         "link":"",
         "content":"contactUs.html",
         "cssClass":"static-content",
         "menu":null
      },
      {
         "id":"rules",
         "leaf":false,
         "description":"Sports Betting Rules",
         "link":"",
         "content":"",
         "cssClass":"",
         "menu":[
            {
               "id":"types",
               "leaf":true,
               "description":"Wager Types",
               "link":"",
               "content":"wagerTypes.html",
               "cssClass":"static-content wager-types",
               "menu":null
            },
            {
               "id":"odds",
               "leaf":true,
               "description":"Odds & Lines",
               "link":"",
               "content":"oddsAndLines.html",
               "cssClass":"static-content",
               "menu":null
            },
            {
               "id":"policies",
               "leaf":true,
               "description":"Rules & Policies",
               "link":"",
               "content":"rulesAndPolicies.html",
               "cssClass":"static-content rules-policies",
               "menu":null
            },
            {
               "id":"bonuses",
               "leaf":true,
               "description":"Sports Bonuses",
               "link":"",
               "content":"sportsBonuses.html",
               "cssClass":"static-content",
               "menu":null
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"conditions",
         "leaf":false,
         "description":"Terms & Conditions",
         "link":"",
         "content":"",
         "cssClass":"",
         "menu":[
            {
               "id":"termsOfService",
               "leaf":true,
               "description":"Terms of Service",
               "link":"",
               "content":"termsOfService.html",
               "cssClass":"static-content",
               "menu":null
            },
            {
               "id":"privacy",
               "leaf":true,
               "description":"Privacy Policy",
               "link":"",
               "content":"privacy.html",
               "cssClass":"static-content",
               "menu":null
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"view",
         "leaf":true,
         "description":"View in: Mobile | Full Site",
         "link":"",
         "content":"view.html",
         "cssClass":"static-content",
         "menu":null
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the model variable to the function and then print it,

```
<li ng-repeat="submenu in menu.menu" id="{{submenu.id}}" class="{{submenu.cssClass}}">
            <a ng-href="{{submenu.content}}" ng-click="ShowAlert(submenu)">{{submenu.description}}</a>
          </li>
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.ShowAlert = function (val) {
     $window.alert(val);
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
$scope.ShowAlert = function (val) {
     alert(val.content);
}
    $scope.menus =  
      [{
        "id": "contact",
        "leaf": true,
        "description": "Contact Us",
        "link": "",
        "content": "contactUs.html",
        "cssClass": "static-content",
        "menu": null
      }, {
        "id": "rules",
        "leaf": false,
        "description": "Sports Betting Rules",
        "link": "",
        "content": "",
        "cssClass": "",
        "menu": [{
          "id": "types",
          "leaf": true,
          "description": "Wager Types",
          "link": "",
          "content": "wagerTypes.html",
          "cssClass": "static-content wager-types",
          "menu": null
        }, {
          "id": "odds",
          "leaf": true,
          "description": "Odds & Lines",
          "link": "",
          "content": "oddsAndLines.html",
          "cssClass": "static-content",
          "menu": null
        }, {
          "id": "policies",
          "leaf": true,
          "description": "Rules & Policies",
          "link": "",
          "content": "rulesAndPolicies.html",
          "cssClass": "static-content rules-policies",
          "menu": null
        }, {
          "id": "bonuses",
          "leaf": true,
          "description": "Sports Bonuses",
          "link": "",
          "content": "sportsBonuses.html",
          "cssClass": "static-content",
          "menu": null
        }]
      }, {
        "id": "conditions",
        "leaf": false,
        "description": "Terms & Conditions",
        "link": "",
        "content": "",
        "cssClass": "",
        "menu": [{
          "id": "termsOfService",
          "leaf": true,
          "description": "Terms of Service",
          "link": "",
          "content": "termsOfService.html",
          "cssClass": "static-content",
          "menu": null
        }, {
          "id": "privacy",
          "leaf": true,
          "description": "Privacy Policy",
          "link": "",
          "content": "privacy.html",
          "cssClass": "static-content",
          "menu": null
        }]
      }, {
        "id": "view",
        "leaf": true,
        "description": "View in: Mobile | Full Site",
        "link": "",
        "content": "view.html",
        "cssClass": "static-content",
        "menu": null
      }]
     ; // response data


  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

  <script data-require="jquery@1.11.3" data-semver="1.11.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller="ListCtrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="menu in menus" id="{{artist.id}}">
        <a ng-href="{{menu.content}}">{{menu.description}}</a>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="submenu in menu.menu">
          <a ng-href="{{submenu.content}}" ng-click="ShowAlert(submenu)">{{submenu.description}}</a>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Concerning `$window.alert("{{menu.content}}");`, Angular does not auto-magically evaluate expressions in all of JavaScript - it'll only evaluate expressions passed to it in templates. These get passed to something like `$compile`, which actually compiles the expression.

You can do something like this using [$scope.$eval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) (which is not as evil as it sounds). That might look *something* like this:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ListCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", "$window",
  function($scope, $http, $window) {
    $http.get('menu.json')
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.menus = response.data.menus; // response data
        $scope.greeting = 'Hello, World!';
        $scope.ShowAlert = function () {
            var alert = $scope.$eval('menu.content')
            $window.alert(alert);
        }
      });
  }
]);
```

Alternatively, you could evaluate the expression inside of the HTML (which is what I would suggest, and what @Sajeetharan posted above, so I won't replicate it here).

---

Note that Angular 1.5+ discourages the use of controllers in this manner because they do not exist in this form in Angular 2.0. I'd highly recommend porting this code to use [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) instead. You'd have a few components; one for the `ListCtrl`, one for each menu, and one for each submenu.

Comment: Why not just do `var alert = $scope.menu.content`?

Comment: There's the possibility that OP actually passes the value from the HTML (which he should do, IMO). In that case, you can't do that. I just translated his question literally, and then addressed the "but you COULD do this" afterwards.